# In the absence of CH, there are just $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ ultrapowers of $\mathbb{R}$ of length $\omega$ up to isomorphism.

Tags: set-theory, model-theory, nonstandard-analysis

We consider structures of the language of ordered fields.
In the absence of CH, there are just $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ ultrapowers of $\mathbb{R}$ of length $\omega$ up to isomorphism. This seems to be a corollary of the following paper:

Linus Kramer, Saharon Shelah, Katrin Tent, Simon Thomas "Asymptotic cones of finitely presented groups" arXiv:math/0306420 [math.GT]
https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0306420

But the paper deals with a more general setting, which is unfamiliar to me. Can a easier argument prove the first statement?

Comment: When you say "in the absence of CH", I assume you mean "assuming $\neg$CH".

Comment: By "just" do you mean "exactly"?  (The word "just" sounds like you're saying the surprising fact is that $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ is an *upper* bound, but that direction is trivial and it is the other direction that is nontrivial.)

Comment: I mean "assuming $\neg \mathrm{CH}$". And I mean "exactly". Thank you.